# Mixing IIS versions in load balanced application

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2019

Can anyone confirm or deny the ability to mix IIS versions in a load balanced application?  We are using an external load balancer appliance with three web servers serving the application.  The application is verified to work independently on the different web servers.  But if I try to include the new server (2019) with the two older servers (2012), I start to get strange application errors that seem to be related to session state management.  The applications are configured exactly the same on all three servers.  I have done some testing where I run just the 2019 server and the application works fine.  I have also tested where the application is run from the two 2012 servers and it works fine even switching between servers during different requests.  So I am leaning toward some issue with mixing the web server versions.

If anyone has some thoughts, I would be grateful.  Bonus "virtual cool points" if someone has any working applications with mixed IIS versions that they'd be willing to talk about.